# How do I display an image stored in Azure File Services in an img tag?

Tags: azure

I'm getting started with Azure File Services and I'm having a 'duh' moment; I'm missing something obvious.

I figured out the API, created a share and uploaded an image from the .net API (not REST API).

the url

http://cooperwrite.file.core.windows.net/cwfiles/me.jpg

is a picture of me. I thought (but am clearly wrong) that this url is also the public url that I would use to render the image.

When I try to access it I get an error. I'm guessing that this url is used to access the file for the purposes of the REST API, but how do I get the url that I would put into an  tag?

This issue has the feel of a protection issue but I can't find any dials to turn.

Thanks,

john

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't.

Essentially for you to display the image using `img` tag, your browser should access the resource anonymously. Currently all requests to file service resources must be authorized (using either `SharedKey` or `ShareKeyLite` authorization scheme) hence you can't access a resource in file service only by specifying a URL.

Your best bet at this time would be to make use of `Azure Blob Storage` and save the file in a container with either `Blob` or `Public` ACL. If your blob container's ACL is private, then you would need a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` with `Read` permission on the image (SAS Token needs to be included in the URL in that case) to be displayed directly in the browser.

Comment: arg! Thank you for your prompt and thorough response. I knew I was missing something. This is good, though, because I get to tear up code I've written over the last few days and start over, said no one ever.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1